# Excel JavaScript API - problem with passing variables between multiple ".then()"

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to pass variables between a chain of ".then()" calls like so:

```
    Excel.run(function (context) {
      var currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      var table = currentWorksheet.tables.getItem("NewTable");
      table.rows.load('count')
      return context.sync()
          .then(function () {
              var rowCount = table.rows.count;
              console.log("There are " + rowCount + " rows in the table.");
              var firstColumn = table.columns.getItem(1);
              firstColumn.load("values");
              return context.sync();
          })
          .then(function () {
              var firstColumnValues = firstColumn.values;
              var summary = {};
              for (var i = 0; i < firstColumnValues.length; i++) {
                  var value = firstColumnValues[i][0];
                  if (summary[value]) {
                      summary[value]++;
                  } else {
                      summary[value] = 1;
                  }
              }
              console.log(summary);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log("Error: " + error);
              if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                  console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
              }
          });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
      if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
          console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
      }
  });
```

But I get an error:

> Error: ReferenceError: firstColumn is not defined

How can I pass variables in a chain of ".then()" calls?

Comment: the return on the .then is the parameter to the next one so if you don't return it then its not avalable, try moving to aysnc/await syntax should simplify the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have your then in the the wrong place

the second then looks like it should be attached to the second sync not the first

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    var currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var table = currentWorksheet.tables.getItem("NewTable");
    table.rows.load("count");
    return context.sync().then(function() {
        var rowCount = table.rows.count;
        console.log("There are " + rowCount + " rows in the table.");
        var firstColumn = table.columns.getItem(1);
        firstColumn.load("values");
        return context
            .sync()
            .then(function() {
                var firstColumnValues = firstColumn.values;
                var summary = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < firstColumnValues.length; i++) {
                    var value = firstColumnValues[i][0];
                    if (summary[value]) {
                        summary[value]++;
                    } else {
                        summary[value] = 1;
                    }
                }
                console.log(summary);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

however i think you would be greatly helped by switching to the async/await syntax, also notice that the use of var for variable declaration is frowned on these days and is a hold over from the early days of javascript before it had the concept of scoping so can lead to some very odd side effects, you should use `const` and `let` (`const` for a variable that will be set once and read many or `let` for a variable that can be set and read many times)

```
Excel.run(async function(context) {
    const currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const table = currentWorksheet.tables.getItem("NewTable");
    table.rows.load("count");
    await context.sync().catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
    const rowCount = table.rows.count;
    console.log("There are " + rowCount + " rows in the table.");
    const firstColumn = table.columns.getItem(1);
    firstColumn.load("values");
    await context.sync().catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
    const firstColumnValues = firstColumn.values;
    const summary = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < firstColumnValues.length; i++) {
        const value = firstColumnValues[i][0];
        if (summary[value]) {
            summary[value]++;
        } else {
            summary[value] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(summary);
});
```

Comment: Thanks the the detailed explanation. That works!